# Как запустить файл с помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Как запустить файл с помощью Python?

Допустим я имею исполняемый файл `openme.exe` и мне надо его запустить или закрыть. Как это сделать?

я пытаюсь это делать имея файл (`d = open('openme.exe')`), и как его запустить/закрыть?

Comment: а как вы пытаетесь это делать? есть пример вашего кода?

Comment: я пытаюсь это делать имея файл (d = open('openme.exe')), и как его запустить/закрыть?

Comment: Используйте `subprocess`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wgslr/3a4a29fd3b6ef0be68c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Windows

```
import os
os.system("C:/path/to/program.exe")
```

```
import os
os.startfile("file/to/start.ext")
```

## *nix

- ```
  import os
  os.system("./path/to/program")
  ```
- #### MacOS:

  ```
  import os
  os.system("./path/to/<app>/MacOS/<app>")
  ```